# how to remove rows in df1 present in df2?

Tags: r

Assume I have two dataframes

```
df1 <- data.frame (name = c("Mike", "Paul", "Paul", "Henry"),
                   age = c(20, 21, 22, 23))

df2 <- data.frame (name = c("Sam", "Paul", "Paul", "Bob"),
                   age = c(26, 30, 22, 23))
```

I would like to remove row 3 from df1, because this row is also present in df2

What is the most elegant way to do this in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `setdiff` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
setdiff(df1, df2)
   name age
1  Mike  20
2  Paul  21
3 Henry  23
```

---

If it is based on subset of column names that are common, use `anti_join`

```
anti_join(df1, df2)
```

In this example, all the columns are common, so by default, it uses `by` as the full column names.  If we want a subset, specify it in `by`

```
anti_join(df1, df2, by = c('name'))
```

Comment: what if I have more columns shared between df and I want to ignore them. Is this argument taken in setdiff

Comment: I updated teh post